# The limit of iterated square root with multiplication under the root, $\sqrt{ a \sqrt{ a \sqrt{a \cdots}}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, radicals

$$
\sqrt{ a  \sqrt{ a  \sqrt{a \cdots}}}=\text{ ?}
$$
options were given as

1. $0$
2. $-a$
3. $a$
4. $1$

i did not know how to solve it or what it was related to. Could anyone please explain the concept and/or provide helpful references or links?

Comment: Did you mean $\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\ldots}}}$?

Comment: Well, I don't like the dots there. They make everything very ambiguous.

Comment: BTW, possible answers are 1 and 3.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. A few things. First, use a descriptive title and leave off personal information. Second, you must include your work and thoughts. Third, use proper grammar. This question will likely not be received well and is likely to be closed.

Comment: **Hint:** Rewrite it as an infinite product of powers of $a$ and take logarithms.

Comment: If $x=\sqrt{ a  \sqrt{ a  \sqrt{a \cdots}}}$ then $x^2=a\sqrt{ a  \sqrt{ a  \sqrt{a \cdots}}}=ax$ so you have $x^2=ax$, so $x(x-a)=0$.  That implies $x=0$ or $x=a$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6):

That's just $a^{1/2}\cdot a^{1/4} \cdots = a^{1/2+1/4+1/8+\cdots}$.

You can use the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} = 1$ to get the answer.

Comment: I understand that this could be written better, but why the downvote?

Comment: @A.P. Perhaps the downvoter thought this answer was claiming $1$ was the correct choice (I did initially).

Answer (score 4):

Let $x_1=\sqrt{a}$, and $x_n=\sqrt{ax_{n-1}}$, for $n\ge 2$ if the limit $$x:=\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n$$
If that limit exist. We have
\begin{align*}
x^2&=a\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\\
&=ax
\end{align*}
So, $x=0$ or $x=a$.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that $x=\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\sqrt{\cdots}}}}$, then squaring both sides, we have $x^2 = a\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\sqrt{a\sqrt{\cdots}}}} = ax$. If we assume $x$ is nonzero, we may divide both sides by $x$ yielding $x=a$. Otherwise, $x=0$; this occurs when $a=0\;(=x)$, so both possible cases are encapsulated in the response $x=a$.

Comment: If $x=0$ and $a=17$ then $x^2 = ax,$ so it's not clear to me why we should conclude that if $x^2=ax$ and $x=0$ then $a=0,$ as you seem to be doing.